# Questions about Asp.net Mvc validating input validity

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a problem in development.

```cs
public class Student
{
     public bool a{get;set;}
     public string b{get;set;}
}
```

B cannot be empty when a is true, otherwise b can be empty. I now need to use Attribute for verification. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using attribute validation, then you'll have to create your own custom attribute and probably try access the `a` value by reflection. Too complex if you ask me...

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-attributes) out on how to create your own validation attributes.

I would rather suggest you use the `IValidatableObject` interface.

```
public class Student : IValidatableObject
{
   public bool a{get;set;}
   public string b{get;set;}

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
   {
      if(a & string.IsNullOrEmpty(b)) 
        yield return new ValidationResult("b is required", new[] {"b"});
   }
}
```

The `Validate` method will run upon validation and attach the message of the `ValidationResult` to the property included in the list (`b` in your case).

Try this solution out.